# Installing 32bit SSRS on 64bit Windows/IIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssrs

I've inherited a situation where I have SQL Server 2005 Standard 32bit running on Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit.

When I come to install SSRS components I'm warned that "Failed to find the ASP.Net Version Registration with Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS)."

In IIS 7 and above, each application pool can run in 32bit mode. If I change all application pools into 32bit mode will this solve the problem?

Are the better alternative solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the problem by following the steps described in the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143293(v=sql.90).aspx

In this link different scenarios including yours have been discussed. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks really promising. I'll investigate any knock on effects of enabling 32bit mode on existing sites in IIS.